# Is the /Developer directory still needed for Xcode in OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macos, xcode

The new Xcode is `.app` and all the package contents are with it, inside the applications folder. Can I just delete `/Developer`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You can delete this folder.** The new /Developer is located in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer, so /Developer can be deleted.

Comment: keep in mind that there may still exist some older build scripts which look for the Developer tools like xcodebuild in /Developer. The simplest way to go around errors caused by this is to symlink /Applications/Xcode.app/Developer to /Developer.

Comment: The suggestion above is horrible, especially in this case as it aims to support legacy structure that is now obsolete. Altering files in .app directories breaks code signing (can test using `code sign`) and is reversed upon upgrading the package anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As of Xcode 4.3, the /Developer directory is no longer needed.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/1006-SW1

Answer (score 1):

Xcode prior to 4.3, which is when Apple transitioned to a single repackaged `.app` for their developer tools, also shipped with an `uninstall-devtools` command line utility. It takes a look at any receipts of Xcode installs on your system and reports that it's removing things like caches, as well. Invoke as:

`sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools`

to do a complete removal of all pre-4.3 Xcode remnants on your system.

Comment: Note that this does affect certain components required by >4.3

Comment: @grg So if you ran this on or after 4.3 - you should reinstall to get the tools needed? (or perhaps they cache data in the same places, so your cached data from newer Xcode would be removed?)